# Difficulty formulating $H_0$ and $H_1$ in hypothesis testing.

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

[image]

For example in this example I don't know  $H_o$ is whether $\eta>28 $ or $\eta<28 $ ,and in general how should we choose $H_o$?
I'm really confused with this,any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you are going to post the exact question, you should give the author/ book title/ page you are quoting.

Comment: The book PROBABILITY, RANDOM VARIABLES, AND STOCHASTIC PROCESSES ,Athanasios Papoulis ,page 382,the Q. 10-2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We assume that the 17 cars are chosen at random from among cars
with approximately normally distributed MPG's.

The claim $H_0$ is that the population mean MPG is 28 or better.
Typing the data into Minitab statistical software (I hope
correctly), we see that the mean of the $n = 17$ tested cars
is $\bar X = 27.67,$ just below 28 MPG, with $S = 4.2.$ Is that evidence that
the claim is untrue?

Notice that a properly formulated null hypothesis must contain
an equal sign. Here $H_0: \mu \ge 28$ against the two-sided
alternative $H_a: \mu < 28.$ The value 28 is used in computing
the t-statistic for this test.

The answer is that the the data do not
give strong evidence against the claim. For such a population
with $\mu = 28$ it would not be unusual to get a random
sample of 17 cars with $\bar X = 27.67$ or smaller. The
probability of that is the P-value = .375. Only if the
P-value is smaller than 0.05 would one normally accuse
the manufacturer of making a false claim.

Printout from Minitab:

```
MTB > Onet 'MPG';
SUBC>   Test 28;
SUBC>   Alternative -1.  # denotes left-sided alternative

One-Sample T: MPG 

Test of mu = 28 vs < 28

                                     95% Upper
Variable   N   Mean  StDev  SE Mean      Bound      T      P
MPG       17  27.67   4.20     1.02      29.45  -0.32  0.375
```

Here is a printout of the data as I typed them, so you
can proofread my data entry. Proofreading is always a good idea.

```
MTB > print 'MPG'

Data Display 

MPG
   19.0   20.0   24.0   25.0   26.0   26.8   27.2   27.5   28.0   28.2   28.4
   29.0   30.0   31.0   32.0   33.3   35.0
```

Finally, you should make sure you understand how the t-statistic -.32 is computed, and how to use a printed t table (DF = n - 1 = 16)
to decide whether to reject $H_0$ at the 5% level of significance.

If you have access to software, you should try this in whatever
kind of software is provided for your course. Input and output formats differ
for various kinds of software, but all require you to show the
null and alternative hypotheses in some way, and all should provide
the same basic results.

Note: Below is the same t-test done in R statistical software.

```
MPG = c(19.0, 20.0, 24.0, 25.0, 26.0, 26.8, 27.2, 27.5, 28.0, 28.2,
       28.4, 29.0, 30.0, 31.0, 32.0, 33.3, 35.0)

t.test(MPG, mu = 28, alternative = "less")

    One Sample t-test

 data:  MPG 
 t = -0.3236, df = 16, p-value = 0.3752
 alternative hypothesis: true mean is less than 28 
 95 percent confidence interval:
      -Inf 29.44757 
 sample estimates:
 mean of x 
  27.67059
```

Comment: So you also mean what we claim is always $H_o$ ?

Comment: @MAh2014. I don't think there is any such universal rule that is useful. ("We" = ?) If alternative two-sided, then $H_0: \mu = \mu_0,$ where $\mu_0$ is a value of particular interest. If one-sided, best to think thru the logic of why expt was done. Here it's easy: seems mfg has made claim, borderline $\bar X$, only interesting test seems to be one that might refute claim. (Follow motivational comments in my Answ.) In practice, probably best analysis here would be to get 2-sided CI for pop mean MPG as guidance what fuel economy prospective buyers might expect (under driving conditions of expt).

Comment: Why do we reject the claim if $t_0.05 (16)$ is more than q=-0.32(what is q exactly?)

Comment: Can't figure out what you're asking. The test statistic $T = -0.3236.$ Reject $H_0$ if T is too small. For a test at the 5% level with $df = 17 - 1 = 16,$ 'too small' means smaller than -1.7459 (from a printed t table).

Answer (score 2):

If you assume that the data are independent and normal distributed (as it is reasonable to do, but it should be written somewhere on your sheet), the solution of this exercise is a typical t-test (because the standard deviation $\sigma$ is not given). We (or the seller) claim(s) that the average mileage is at least 28, thus
\begin{equation}
H_0: \mu \ge \mu_0 = 28. 
\end{equation}
Now, for this situation, the alternative-hypothesis is $H_1: \mu < \mu_0 = 28$ (one-sided), because we want to test if our claim $H_0: \mu \ge \mu_0= 28$ is reasonable, which means that we reject our null-hypothesis $H_0$ if the data gives a value too smaller than $28$.

Comment: I disagree, it says "at least 28 miles per gallon" in the prompt. That suggests a one-sided test.

Comment: True, my mistake. Thank you :)

Comment: So you mean that $H_o$ is what we claim,and $H_1$ the complement?Thank you.

Comment: That's still not consistent with the usual formulation. Normally, $H_0$ *specifies* the value of the parameter while $H_1$ is *some alternative* to $H_0$ (i.e. some scenario which implies the negation of $H_0$ but may not be the entire negation of $H_0$). The way I rationalize this is that we first identify $H_1$, the thing we want to claim, which is that $\mu>28$. Then we consider the negation of $H_1$ and look at the worst possible case in that negation for supporting $H_1$, which will be $\mu=28$. That case is our null hypothesis.

Comment: Why $H_1: \mu >28$ and not $H_1: \mu <28$? If our data gives a value larger than 28, then the claim "at least 28" is true. Am I wrong?

Comment: It depends who you are in the scenario. As the manufacturer, you want to argue $\mu>28$ so that will be your $H_1$. As the consumer, you probably want to argue $\mu<28$ (since you're skeptical of their claim) so that will be your $H_1$. Either way is fine, but $H_0$ will be $\mu=28$ either way.

Comment: So what should we do for examples in exams?which one should we choose?!(as the answer differs.)

Comment: @MAh2014 Again it comes down to your perspective. If you make a test to the left, you find that it is reasonable to believe that the mpg is at least 28, i.e. you do not reject the null. If you make a test to the right, you find that it is not reasonable to believe the mpg is less than or equal to 28, so you reject the null. Either way the given claim is plausible.